# Why my empty postgres database is 7MB?

Tags: postgresql

I just created an new database and it already takes up 7MB. Do you know what is taking up this much space? Is there a way to get the "real" size of the database used as in how much data is stored?

```
0f41ba72-a1ea-4516-a9f0-de8a3609bc4a=> select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database()));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 7055 kB
(1 row)

0f41ba72-a1ea-4516-a9f0-de8a3609bc4a=> \dt
No relations found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, even you don't created any relation yet the new database is *not* empty. When a `CREATE DATABASE` is issued, Postgres copy a `TEMPLATE` database - which comes with catalog tables - to a new database. In fact, *"Nothing is created, everything is transformed"*. You can use commands below to inspect this:

```
--Size per table
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(oid)), relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND NOT relisshared;

--Total size
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_total_relation_size(oid))) FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND NOT relisshared;

--Total size of databases
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid)), datname FROM pg_database;
```

A quote from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html):

> By default, the new database will be created by cloning the standard
>   system database template1.

Answer (score 2):

An *empty* database contains [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html) and [The Information Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html).

Execute this query to see them:

```
select nspname as schema, relname as table, pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)
from pg_class c
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
order by 3 desc;

       schema       |            table            | pg_total_relation_size 
--------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 pg_catalog         | pg_depend                   |                1146880
 pg_catalog         | pg_proc                     |                 950272
 pg_catalog         | pg_rewrite                  |                 589824
 pg_catalog         | pg_attribute                |                 581632
... etc
```

You can get the total size of non-system relations with the query:

```
select sum(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid))
from pg_class c
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
where nspname not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pg_toast');
```

The query returns `null` on *empty* database.

Answer (score 0):

Every PostgreSQL databases has own system catalogue .. 7MB. So your numbers are correct. PostgreSQL is designed for client-server architecture and 1GB and longer databases - so this cost is not significant.

If you need reduced space allocation, you can try embedded databases like SQLite or Firebird.